# Angular 2 change detection on array push of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

I have a 'Schedule' typescript class and a 'selectedSchedule' variable of this 'Schedule' type.
Schedule:

```
export class Schedule{
   scheduleId: string;
   sheduleDate: Date = new Date();
   scheduleName: string;
   jobs: Job[];
   unscheduledEmployeesCount: number = 0;
   idleEquipmentCount: number = 0;
   unscheduledTrucksCount: number = 0;
}
```

I'm binding this variable and it's properties in the HTML by utilizing interpolation. My problem is I'm using a *ngFor to iterate and display each 'job'...

```
<div class="job" *ngFor="let j of selectedSchedule.jobs">
   <div [ngClass]="{'hasEmployees': j.jobEmployees.length > 0 }">
      <div *ngFor="let e of j.jobEmployees">
         {{e.employee['name'] !== null ? e.employee['name'] : e.name}}
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

whenever the user triggers the 'addJob()' method by clicking a button, the newly created 'job' doesn't get detected by Angular and results in the properties of the 'job' to be null, most notably the 'jobEmployees' of each 'job'. I understand Angular doesn't detect changes to an array when you push/remove objects out of the box. I'm looking for a solution to pick up on these changes when a user adds a new job. I have tried to reassign the 'selectedSchedule' and it's 'jobs' property with no success. Also have tried to slice() the jobs array with the thought of 'recreating' the array.
I'm currently making an extra http request to get the schedule's jobs again, which seems to prevent the null property problems, but I'm hoping to find a more efficient solution.

The addJob() method in component:

```
addJob() {
    var newJob: Job;
    this.data.addJob(this.selectedSchedule.scheduleId).subscribe(addedJob => {
        this.selectedSchedule.jobs.push(addedJob);
        this.data.loadSchedules().subscribe(success => {
            if (success) {
                this.selectedSchedule = this.data.schedules.find(schedule => schedule.scheduleId === this.selectedSchedule.scheduleId);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

addJob() method in data service:

```
addJob(scheduleId: string) {
    return this.http.get("/api/job/addjob", { headers: this.headers, params: { scheduleId: scheduleId } })
        .map((job: Job) => {
            return job;
        });
}
```

'Job' class:

```
export class Job {
   jobId: string;
   jobName: string;
   jobNumber: string;
   jobEmployees: Array<Employee> = new Array<Employee>();
   jobEquipment: Array<Equipment> = new Array<Equipment>();
   jobTrucks: Array<Truck> = new Array<Truck>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **[`ChangeDetectorRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)**,Normally this is done by Angulars change detection which gets notified by its zone that change detection should happen. Whenever you manually subscribe in a component, angular marks the component instance as dirty whenever the subscribed stream emits a value.

Try calling it manually as follows,

```
   this.selectedSchedule = this.data.schedules.find(schedule => schedule.scheduleId === this.selectedSchedule.scheduleId);
   this.cdRef.detectChanges();
```

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan the code you suggested still gives the same 'Cannot convert null or undefined to object' error for each 'jobEmployee'

Comment: why dont you take the data from the server without adding to it locally?

Comment: I'm sorry, still kinda new to Angular. Can you elaborate a little more? When page loads, I make an initial call to get the schedules from the server and each time a job is added, I make a GET request to add a job to that schedule as well as return that newly created job back to client. Thanks @Sajeetharan